# Editing a predefined Table array

Tags: excel

I am adding additional information to an excel document, it has a number of predefined table arrays and a number of VLOOKUPS using these. Such as

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP($A7,DataItemsDescrips,2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($A7,DataItemsDescrips,2,FALSE))
```

I wish to add additional cells to the predefined table arrays. How is this done in excel 2007

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Jerry. I had a similar issue from the questions above and this works witht he most recent version also! I check several sites before seeing this answer. It was the most direct and worked!
(1) Formulas, (2) Name Manager, (3) Choose table array needing editing, (4) Edit formual

4 easy steps.

Answer (score 1):

Are you maybe referring to Named Ranges? By this, I mean the "DataItemsDescrips" you have in the formula you gave as example.

If yes, you can access and modify them through "Formulas" > "Name Manager" and you should find the "DataItemsDescrips" in the list. Select it and you can change the range it refers to.